# rails - how much faster are number comparisons vs text comparisons

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a pretty expensive method in my model that compares text items of arrays for many many items.

It runs **really** slow. If I use a relational database table and compare the ID's only, will my method run a lot faster?

/EDIT

I'm attempting to benchmark the below:

```
 @matches = @location_matches.sort do |l1, l2|
      l1.compute_score(current_user) <=> l2.compute_score(current_user)
    end

    @matches.reverse!
```

Comment: Please post a example of your model. It is too vague currently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be short, I guess number comparison will be faster because comparing string is about comparing character after character (advice: in Ruby use symbols when you can, their comparison is much faster).

Whatever, you'll find [there](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html), everything you need to benchmark and get your detailled results.

A code sample:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 50000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("for:")   { for i in 1..n; a = "1"; end }
  x.report("times:") { n.times do   ; a = "1"; end }
  x.report("upto:")  { 1.upto(n) do ; a = "1"; end }
end
```

The result:

```
                user     system      total        real
   for:     1.050000   0.000000   1.050000 (  0.503462)
   times:   1.533333   0.016667   1.550000 (  0.735473)
   upto:    1.500000   0.016667   1.516667 (  0.711239)
```

Comment: @mu is too short: ahah! I usually prefer to learn fishing rather than being fed :)

Comment: I know, I suck :| but I posted my code, how would I benchmark that? thanks all

Comment: @masedesign: You definitely DON'T suck, you're learning and asking yourself excellent questions, that's the path to follow. I suggest you use the benchmark in your Rails console so that the whole environment is loaded.

Comment: @masedesign: are still waiting for answers?

Answer (score 3):

Your first task is to replace that [`sort`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001480) with a [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001481), you can also skip the [`reverse!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000241) by sorting things in the desired order in the first place:

```
@matches = @location_matches.sort_by { |loc| -loc.compute_score(current_user) }
```

The `sort` method will have to do many comparisons while sorting and each comparison requires two `compute_score` calls, the `sort_by` method does a [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_Transform) internally so your expensive `compute_score` will only be called once per entry. The negation inside the block is just an easy way to reverse the sort order (I'm assuming that your scores are numeric).

Fix up the obvious performance problem and then move on to benchmarking various solutions (but be sure to benchmark `sort` versus `sort_by` just to be sure that "obvious" matches reality).

Comment: Thanks so much, this was very helpful. Turns out my problem is: `listing_location.distance_from(user_location, :units=>:miles) > distance.to_f ? nil : listing` which is used by geokit to determine distances. Bleh, unfixable it seems.

Comment: @masedesign: That's probably doing a [haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) internally. If you only care about a small radius, a simple Euclidean metric (or even a Manhattan metric) as an approximation might be good enough to filter things, then haversine a smaller set to get real distances.